# Why does liquibase references by tableName stop working?

Tags: database, postgresql, liquibase, changeset

I always reference a table foreign key by specifying the table name if the primary key is just "id". For example this would always work:

```
              - column:
              name: user_id
              type: nvarchar(36)
              constraints:
                nullable: false
                references: user
                foreignKeyName: fk_users_user
```

Just referencing the production table would be enough to map the foreignKey to the correct field. However, it seems that it doesn't work for a specific case.

I have an addColumn changeSet as follows:

```
  - changeSet:
  id: SDAC-X
  author: benjamin.bajic@antcolony.io
  changes:
    - addColumn:
        columns:
          - column:
              name: conversation_id
              type: nvarchar(36)
              constraints:
                nullable: false
                references: conversation
                foreignKeyName: fk_message_conversation
        tableName: message
```

And for some reason this does not work. I get the UnexpectedLiquibaseException: Don't know how to find table and column names from conversation error. I know that I can fix this by specifying the column name and it does work, but I'm curious as to why it does not work in this one scenario? I reference the very same column when creating a new column in a different table in the same fashion and it runs just fine, like so:

```
- createTable:
        tableName: conversation_message
        columns:
          - column:
              name: id
              type: nvarchar(36)
              constraints:
                primaryKey: true
                nullable: false
          - column:
              name: conversation_id
              type: nvarchar(36)
              constraints:
                nullable: false
                references: conversation
                foreignKeyName: fk_conversation_message_conversation
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why this happens?

Comment: I know it's been a long time since this was posted, but do you have the exact text of the error message? Or If you were able to resolve it, how did you do it?

Comment: @tabbyfoo I didn't manage to resolve it. For this example here, I just explicitly specified the referenced column, tableName(referencedColumnName).

The exact text of the error message was as follows:

Error: Don't know how to find table and column names from TableName liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: Don't know how to find table and column names from TableName

Comment: I will bring this to the team when I'm back online Tuesday and see what I can find out, but have you seen this question in the meantime? It has an accepted suggested answer for the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302249/unexpectedliquibaseexception-dont-know-how-to-find-table-and-column-names

Comment: Yes I have seen this question. The exact same thing works for me too however I have other changeSets that are part of my changelog file which do not have the brackets included and still work fine.